# Apache2 - Password protecting web directories & its subdirectories

Tags: apache, apache2.2

I had couple of virtual host configured & they are pointing to specific directories of different user. User access generated output file from their respective directories. those directories also contain no. of sub-directories & sub-directories created & deleted at runtime by different applications.

I read about htaccess file on couple of blogs something like

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-setup-apache-password-protect-directory-with-htaccess-file/

but it required to create htaccess file in each directory, that not possible. What I need is some kind of authentication mechanism that apply to all virtual host & its sub-directories at any level

how to do that?